# Recommended way to create small utility classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a class (say class A, with A.h and A.m files). This class needs a utility class, and I'm too lazy to create Utility.h and Utility.m

Is there a way to include its definition (implementation) in A.m? Is it unavoidable to create its declaration (interface)?

What are the best practices in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course there is a way: just add the implementation to the file. The compiler doesn't care where your implementation is, as long as it has all relevant declarations at hand. Its the linker's job to sort out where the object code actually is.

And no, you cannot avoid creating a definition. So create it where ever your other code needs it. If you need the helper class only for class A then you should prefer putting the interface declaration into the implementation file, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add methods to the class `@implementation` without declaring them in the interface. Not even in a private `A ()` category. The compiler will complain about missing selectors unless you are careful enough to all methods before (in source code order) its first utilization.

So, technically yes, you can avoid the interface declaration.

You have some additional choices that don't require the creation of a new class with its pair of files and the tremendous effor of picking a new class name:

1. Create a category `A (Utils)` in the same A.h/m files
2. Create a category `A (Utils)` only in A.m (slightly faster coding)
3. Create plain C functions in A.h/m

In all these cases you need to write pretty much the same code. I'd prefer option 2 and then extract the category to actual files or even a different class when the methods are needed elsewhere.

Comment: I think option 2 is good but would always create it in a separate file. If you want to unit test the utility functions, it might be hard to create test classes if your main (A.m) includes many other dependencies.